# Yii 2 best practice инструкция для добавления авторизации\регистрации для basic шаблона

Tags: php, авторизация, yii2, регистрация

Может тема уже и изъеденная, но мне кажется каждый городит свой велосипед. Каким наиболее простым и удобным способом сделать авторизацию и регистрацию? Думаю коллективным мнением этот вопрос довольно просто

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, лучше всего рассмотреть два варианта: 1. адаптация контроллера и моделей из advanced; 2. Модуль [Yii2-user](http://yii2-user.dmeroff.ru)